# ipython's strange behavior with directories named "code"

Tags: python, ipython

I can't import anything from directories named "code".

I have the following directory structure:

```
In [1]: ls
code/          data/          pickles/
code_copy/     documentation/ submissions/
```

code_copy is an exact copy of code

```
In [2]: ls code_copy/
santander.py              
__init__.py               santander.pyc             


In [3]: ls code
santander.py              
__init__.py               santander.pyc
```

However, the behavior of these two directories is different when I try to import something from them. For example, I can't import santander.py from code

```
In [4]: from code.
code.InteractiveConsole      code.compile_command
code.InteractiveInterpreter  code.interact

In [5]: from code import santander
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-e36a94117eb8> in <module>()
----> 1 from code import santander

ImportError: cannot import name santander
```

while I'm able to do it from code_copy

```
In [6]: from code_copy.  
code_copy.santander            

In [7]: from code_copy import santander

In [8]:
```

Is this ipython's behavior normal? Is "code" a especial name? How can this be fixed?

Comment: Fix: don't use the name of a standard module as a name for your own module. https://docs.python.org/2/library/code.html

Comment: there's a code object in Python that you can get from `compile` function. It could be that's what's messing with you.

Comment: Thanks, @kindall. Is that the only simple fix? I'd say that that didn't happen to me in another computer with perhaps another ipython installation/configuration. I'm only ~75% sure about this. I don't usually use ipython shell/notebook

Comment: Well, you could also change the search path so it looks in that directory first for modules, but then you couldn't use the Python `code` module.

Comment: Thanks, @kindall. I'll be happy to accept if you make it an answer